# Dealing with Timeout in Cloud Functions for Paginated API call

Tags: python, loops, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have an API call in python which loops over more than 100 pages each with 200 rows. I am using a while loop which runs well locally. I want to load the resulting dataframe to bigquery using cloud functions but since it takes more than 9 mins, it will timeout in cloud. Any help to adjust this accordingly so data is loaded in batches?

NB: I have tried cloud storage buckets, iterating and loading without concat

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

 
page = 1
data_nested = []
loop = []

while data_nested is not None:
    data = [('vendor_id', xx),('vendor_auth_code','xxxx'),('results_per_page',200),('page',page)]
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers , data = data)
    data_nested = response.json()['response']
    data_flattened = pd.json_normalize(data_nested)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_flattened)
    loop.append(df)
    if len(df.index)==0:
       break
    page += 1
final=pd.concat(loop)
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the pandas code outside the loop? so that It will be one execution if converting it to df (dataframe). Also, you can try to deploy your code to [Cloud Functions using 2nd generation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout#:~:text=timeout%20duration%20is-,60%20minutes,-(3600%20seconds)%20for), the maximum timeout is 60minutes (3600 seconds) for http triggers

Comment: Do you know in advance the number of pages? Do you know , immediately in the response, if you have a new page to call? Have you a rate limit on the target URL?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No, the number of pages is unknown in advance, so the loop runs until there is nothing to return. From the api doc, 'results_per_page' limit is 200

Comment: @Darwin Yes, I have already tried that, still timesout

Answer (score 0):

@Darwin answer was most helpful - I deployed my code to 2nd gen cloud functions and loaded historical data in batches. It's a bit of manual  work but got the job done. I then used webhooks to update the data